What is the difference in MUI useTheme() from '@mui/material/styles' vs '@mui/material'?
I'm using the theme object within a component but vsCode quick fix is suggesting to import useTheme hook from '@mui/material', and not even listing '@mui/material/styles'.
Would I run into any issues if I used the import from '@mui/material' since I'm already importing the components from there?
